# Change type of member vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to figure out how to change type of vector. The class foo represents data structure, that is used by many algorithms. However, the new requirements is to store results of the last processing algorithms as a floating point data. Below code show the minimum version of the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class foo{
    protected:
    vector<int> a; 
    public:
    virtual void print(){
        cout<<"foo type of " <<sizeof(a[0])<<endl;
    };
};

class bar: public foo
{
    vector<double> a;
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.print();

    bar b;

    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the "program" is:

```
foo type of 4
foo type of 4
```

My expectation is:

```
foo type of 4
foo type of 8
```

So how can I obtain such results without a huge number of code repetition. 
I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: You cannot change the type of an inherited member.

Comment: You should try using templates. Change your vector<int> in foo to a templated class with vector<type> a;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to types known at compile time, static polymorphism (using templates) is typically more powerful than runtime polymorphism (using virtual functions).

Your expectation is based on the wrong assumption that virtual functions are implicitly redefined in derived classes. Since you're not overriding the virtual function, you don't benefit from it being virtual, you could as well have omitted the `virtual` keyword. Because it's defined in the base class, it will always refer to the `a` member in the base class.

MPI_What's answer shows a possible approach using templates. **Edit:** For a solution based on runtime polymorphism, you could combine static with dynamic polymorphism, leading to a technique called *type erasure*:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void print() const = 0;
}

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void print() const
    {
        ...
    }

    std::vector<T> a;
};
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much

Comment: I found another problem. Your solution works only if print() is a type of void. How can I return value of first vector's a element?

Comment: @user1877600 What type should the value have? How does your base class look?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using templates like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Type>
class foo{
protected:
    std::vector<Type> a;
public:
    void print(){
    std::cout << "Foo type of " << sizeof(a[0]) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<int> f;
    f.print();

    foo<double> b;
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Foo type of 4
Foo type of 8
```

Comment: Is it possible without the template? I am using this data structures in many files so adjustment code to template costs a lot

Comment: @user1877600 If you want your class to work with arbitrary types, templates are the best way to avoid code duplication. If you need a runtime-polymorphic interface, you can use type erasure as outlined in my answer.